# add watermarks on images

Tags: php, watermark

I using codeigniter upload.php v1.0 but i want to add watermark.

```
if ( ! @copy($this->file_temp, $this->upload_path.$this->file_name))
        {
            if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, $this->upload_path.$this->file_name))
            {
                $this->set_error('upload_destination_error', 'error');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

I wrote the following codes after this line

```
//**Watermark
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng($this->upload_path.'/indir.png');
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->upload_path.$this->file_name);

    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

    //**Watermark
```

but not working

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. “Not working” is not a useful problem description.

Comment: _“I wrote the following codes after this line”_ - what exactly do you mean by that? That it is basically just the two code blocks above executed right after one another? The first part is to process the uploaded image, store it somewhere on the server; the second one is to _output_ an image directly to the browser. So trying to combine these two into one step, probably doesn’t make much sense to begin with. You would either need to add your watermark to the image _before_ it gets stored; or add it dynamically _every time_ it gets send to a client.